# angular2 zone.js making automatic sock.js calls

Tags: javascript, websocket, angular

Hi I am using Angular2 with webpack based on this seed https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed

I am not quite sure for what angular is using zone.js but when I am starting my app and viewing the console output I get this Error every few seconds:

```
zone.js?e3a6:101 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://10.1.1.10/#/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:8081/sockjs-node/info?t=1461960793084'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I understand why the error is happening, but do not know why this request is even made in the first place, especially every few seconds. My web app is working and seems not to be concerned by this error, maybe somebody could explain to me why zone.js does this request, and if there is a way to disable it.

Comment: angular using zone.js for detect changes in data, can see more here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUxD91DWkGM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is made by the "Automatic Refresh/Hot Module Replacement" feature of webpack-dev-server. It injects a script for refreshing the page when changes happen in the source.

To disable this feature, replace `--inline` with `--lazy` in `package.json` to:

```
{
  "scripts": {
     ...
    "server": "node node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --lazy --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached --port 3000  --content-base src",
     ...
  }
}
```